# React: store state to template literals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I create js code in a separate file (no matter why, I just need to understand the principle), which consists of just a literal, for example:

```
export default `
<div>
</div>
`
```

and import it into the component as follows:
`import * as content from ./filename.js` after which I can refer to him as follows, for example: `document.write(content)` and there are no problems with this

But it is not at all clear to me how in such a construction it is possible to store the state.

In the component where I import this code, there is a props called `body`

Is it possible to make the following construction work: ?

```
export default `
<div>
${this.props.body}
</div>
`
```

Sorry if I didn't write too accurately. Ready to quickly answer all questions

Comment: It would help to clarify this. Does the export actually need to be a string like in your question, or can you export a function? This question is tagged for React, but React has no way to handle string-based templates like this.

Comment: I need to rewrite the whole page, so I used this method. Tell me, please, if i try to wrap all this export code in a function, will the `document.write` work? Could you tell me how to write such a structure correctly?

Comment: React really isn't designed for usage via `document.write`. Are you actually trying to use React, or are you leaving React behind in favor of this string-based approach?

Comment: let me tell you briefly about the problem I was facing. I need to redraw the entire page (completely replacing html) if there is an query in the URL. so I use this prehistoric method, it seemed to me the best solution. If i write the code directly inside the component, everything works well, but it takes up too much space, so I decided to put it in a separate file

Comment: Generally you'd use something like `react-router` to handle that, so React itself would be responsible for choosing the new set of components to render based on the URL of the page. `document.write` is almost never used in modern JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i see problem right, you ask not about react but ES6 template strings.
As i understand, when you write a literal string ${variable} it have context of current scope and translate to value before you export it. 
So you have only way to declare these variables inside your template file or use template engine at import side.

As variant, you can create proxy function

```
//module.js
export default function(context) {
    return `test ${context.teststring} test`
}

// main.js with teststring in scope
import withContext from "./module";
document.write(withContext(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

A template literal uses `${...}`:

```
export default `
<div>
${this.props.body}
</div>
`
```

Comment: I made a mistake when I wrote question, I apologize. in my code that's right. I just get an error: `Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`